# Pandas Groupby of 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Is there a way to group 2 dataframes, so if i have

```
index      col1     col2    |  index     col1     col2 
0          AA       12      |  0          AA       12
1          AB       13      |  1          AB       13
2          AC       14      |  2          AD       15
```

(NOTE: "|" used to seperate the 2 df)

I would get

```
index    col1   col2
0        AA      24
1        AB      26
2        AC      14 
3        AD      15
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AA','AB','AC'], 'col2':[12,13,14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AA','AB','AD'], 'col2':[12,13,15]})
```

Now, you can use `concat` to stack them and `group` them:

```
df = pd.concat( [df1, df2],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
df = df.groupby('col1').sum().reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2
0   AA    24
1   AB    26
2   AC    14
3   AD    15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append DF2 to DF1 and then groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AA', 'AB','AC'], 'col2': [12,13,14]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AA', 'AB','AD'], 'col2': [12,13,15]})

df1=df1.append(df2)
df1.groupby('col1').sum()
```